# Scrollview implementation with autolayout for a Universal App using xcode 6

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have been struggling past few days to implement a view that is scrollable using autolayout in Xcode 6.0 for Universal Apps. I have looked at many examples. However I am not able to get this working.

I am implementing this way:
View
--ScrollView
---ContentView (This view has all the subviews)
----- Labels
----- TextFields
----- Buttons
----- TableView
----- ImageeView

Setting the constraints of ScrollView to the View as zero for all the four edges. And constraints for the ContentView to ScrollView similarly all zeroes. Then I am adding constraints to each control setting the height and width. And the first control has the Center Horizontally and the last Control has the constraint to the Content View.

I can get the screen working if I don't add the scrollview. It is pretty confusing..

Unfortunately this does not resize on the iPhone. I am using .Xib for the Builder Interface. Please help me with an example or please guide me to any information that I can use to resolve my issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you adding all the objects by code or in your Xib file?

Comment: @YuviGr, I am adding all the objects in Xib file.

Answer (score 0):

You can't create the scrollView contentView in the xib file.
You need to add then dynamically.

After you set the scrollView autolayout constraints in code you add all the objects:

1) set the contentView size (this could be as big as you want,don't need to set constraints to the contentView)

2) add the objects you want (labels, views, button...) to the contentView by calling

```
[scrollView addSubView:<your subView>];
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I did as you have adviced. Unfortunately the app is not getting resized. I have the xib file having the autolayout and size classes checked. My code for the constraint is as below, please help me understand how I achieve this. Do you have any example to share? Any information would help me greatly. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: This is how I have coded after creating the scroll view, content view and before adding the objects to contentview.   translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints= NO ;
    viewsDictionary = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(scrollView);
    
    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[scrollView]|" options:0 metrics: 0 views:viewsDictionary]];
    
    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[scrollView]|" options:0 metrics: 0 views:viewsDictionary]];